# Swift после гашения экрана запросы перестают идти на сервер

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Всем привет есть приложение которое каждые 15 секунд проверяет обновления на сервере .Но стоит экрану погаснуть как через определенное время данные перестают посылаться когда включаешь экран все окей работает .С чем может быть связано такое ограничение что это и как его обойти .

Comment: Это нормально. Потому что Ваше приложение не сервис.

Comment: KoVadim а как сделать его сервисом?в андроиде так и идет сервис )скажите в какую сторону идтм

Comment: Это не обойти, Apple не разрешает делать запросы, когда устройство находиться в спящем режиме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В iOS нет такой вещи как сервис. Приложение после того как уходит в фон некоторое время может проработать, а затем "замораживается". Время перед "замораживанием" можно продлить, запросив у ОС, но это не на долго (около 3-5 минут).

Сценарий "просто проверять каждые 15 секунд обновления на сервере" никак не сделать. Да и как это будет высаживать аккумулятор.

Приложение будет работать в фоне только если это: audio, voip, location, newstand. Но если функционал не будет соответствовать задекларированному поведению, приложение будет отклонено.

Comment: А как насчет whatsapp там же получаешь уведомления

Comment: @elik Вы о пуш-уведомлениях? Там совсем другой механизм работы. И пока не будет взаимодействия пользователя (нажмет на уведомление или иконку приложения), приложение останется замороженным. Ну и WhatsApp VoIP клиент.